# coreplot: Joining missing line points in scatter plot

Tags: ios, xcode, charts, core-plot, scatter-plot

I have a graph with multiple scatter plots in same plot area.... like the image.
For "FC" series, I don't have values for 11:00 and 12:00 (as you can see)...  but I need to join these points by line (points A and B).

Here is the image: 
[!image](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-FKuZ3G6ytgc/UMn0gLgrMYI/AAAAAAAAACY/K7etqjSVVz4/s1600/graph.png)

How can I do It?

Thanks!
Almir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't provide data points for the missing section at all. In your example, the red plot only has four points, at 0900, 1000, 1300, and 1400.